# Return multiple rows grouped by a column and named by other column value

Tags: sqlite, field, rename

Not sure if title is formulated correctly, so there is better explanation:

Table: **users_data**

```
uid | key    | value
1   | "age"  | "23"
1   | "city" | "London"
1   | "name" | "John"
2   | "age"  | "19"
2   | "city" | "Tokio"
2   | "name" | "Aiko"
```

Query: Select data of users aged 23.

Result should look like this:

```
uid | age  | city     | name
1   | "23" | "London" | "John"
```

Don't even have current code since I have no idea if it is possible to name columns by value of field, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You absolutely can do this easily in SQL... unfortunately, I don't think SQLite supports Pivot by.

The alternative is a bit more code intensive, and only works if the keys are known in advance.

```
Select name.uid name.value, city.value, age.value from
       (Select uid, value from users_data where key="name") as name
  join (Select uid, value from users_data where key="city") as city on name.uid=city.uid
  join (Select uid, value from users_data where key="age") as age on name.uid=age.uid
```